# Why are JQuery click events are working only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just learned to do some javascript with jquery, and I'm trying to do a simple login/subscribe form, with a button that allows you to change between "sign-in" and "log-in" dynamically.

But when I click on the buttons that changes the form, they work only once each.
I can do like Sign-in -> Log-in -> Sign-in page but buttons aren't working after that.

Sorry for my bad english I'm trying to improve myself though :)

Thanks for your help !

Source code :

```
function buildLogin() {
    $(".allowedOnConnect").remove();

    let titre = $("<h2>Dota AZZA, two players, one challenge.</h2>")
        .appendTo("#content");

    let form = $("<div id='form'></div>")
        .appendTo('#content');

    let incriptionButton = $("<button type='button'>No account ? Click here !</button>")
        .click(function (){
            $("#form").empty();
            inscription.appendTo('#form');
        });

    let connexionButton = $("<button type='button'>You already have an account ? Click here !</button>")
        .click(function (){
            $("#form").empty();
            connexion.appendTo('#form');
        });

    let connexion = $("<form id='formLogin' method='POST' action=''></form>")
        .append("<input id='id' type='text' name='id' placeholder='Identifiant'/></br>")
        .append("<input id='pwd' type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Mot de passe'/></br>")
        .append("<input type='submit' value='Connexion'/>")
        .append(incriptionButton)
        .submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/php/login.php",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data['id_user']) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
                if (!data['is_filled']) {
                    $("#errorNotFilled").remove();
                    $("#formLogin").append("<p id='errorNotFilled'>Please fill the form</p>");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    let inscription = $("<form id='formSignIn' method='POST' action=''></form>")
        .append("<input id='id' type='text' name='id' placeholder='Identifiant'/></br>")
        .append("<input id='mail' type='text' name='mail' placeholder='Mail'/></br>")
        .append("<input id='pwd' type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Mot de passe'/></br>")
        .append("<input id='pwdConfirm' type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Confirmer le mot de passe'/></br>")
        .append("<input type='submit' value='Connexion'/>")
        .append(connexionButton)
        .submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/php/signin.php",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data['id_user']) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
                if (!data['is_filled']) {
                    $("#errorNotFilled").remove();
                    $("#formLogin").append("<p id='errorNotFilled'>Please fill this form</p>");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });


    connexion.appendTo('#form');

}
```

Comment: Do you have any error in console.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that when removing elements from the DOM (e.g. by using `.empty()` in your case or `.remove()`), all event handlers will also be removed from the elements. Therefore, your click handlers will no longer be there. Instead of creating your elements in the variables, I would suggest wrapping their creation in functions, which you can then reuse.

```js
    function buildLogin() {
      $(".allowedOnConnect").remove();
      $("<h2>Deux joueurs, un défi.</h2>")
        .appendTo("#content");

      $("<div id='form'></div>")
        .appendTo('#content');

      let incriptionButton = function() {
        return $("<button type='button'>Pas de compte ? Cliquez ici !</button>")
          .click(function () {
            $("#form").empty();
            inscription().appendTo('#form');
          });
   }

      let connexionButton = function() {
        return $("<button type='button'>Déja un compte ? Cliquez ici !</button>")
          .click(function () {
            $("#form").empty();
            connexion().appendTo('#form');
          });
     }

      let connexion = function () {
        return $("<form id='formLogin' method='POST' action=''></form>")
          .append("<input id='id' type='text' name='id' placeholder='Identifiant'/></br>")
          .append("<input id='pwd' type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Mot de passe'/></br>")
          .append("<input type='submit' value='Connexion'/>")
          .append(incriptionButton()) // <-- function call here
          .submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/php/login.php",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data['connected']) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
                if (!data['is_filled']) {
                    $("#errorNotFilled").remove();
                    $("#formLogin").append("<p id='errorNotFilled'>Merci de remplir le formulaire</p>");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
      };

    let inscription = function () {
      return $("<form id='formSignIn' method='POST' action=''></form>")
        .append("<input id='id' type='text' name='id' placeholder='Identifiant'/></br>")
        .append("<input id='mail' type='text' name='mail' placeholder='Mail'/></br>")
        .append("<input id='pwd' type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Mot de passe'/></br>")
        .append("<input id='pwdConfirm' type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Confirmer le mot de passe'/></br>")
        .append("<input type='submit' value='Connexion'/>")
        .append(connexionButton()) // <-- function call here
        .submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/php/signin.php",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data['connected']) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
                if (!data['is_filled']) {
                    $("#errorNotFilled").remove();
                    $("#formLogin").append("<p id='errorNotFilled'>Merci de remplir le formulaire</p>");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
      };
      
   connexion().appendTo('#form');
    }
    
    buildLogin();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

This way, you will always get a fresh instance of your elements with the event handlers attached.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `return` inside the function, I just fixed that.

Comment: The code is now an actual working snippet. You can try it out directly, it works fine.